# Visual Studio ALT code symbols

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pi

I'm looking for a list of ALT code symbols within Visual Studio 2010.

Specifically, I was looking for the PI symbol. I did a little search and found that it should be ALT+227 or ALT+960. I've tried both in VS but the symbols provided are different, hence why I'm asking this question here.

Help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the charmap.exe utility.

Comment: make sure the file you are editing uses some kind of unicode format

Answer (score 1):

at least in visual studio 2013, pi is at alt+995. I don't know why it is different than in the rest of windows, and I typed it out of luck while randomly stabbing around for lambda

Answer (score 0):

ALT+227, based on IBM Code Page 437 / MS-DOS, is correct for Greek Small Letter Pi **π**. See here: [Windows Alt Code Symbols](https://altcodeunicode.com/windows-alt-code-symbols/)

ALT+960, which is the Unicode Decimal Codepoint for Greek Small Letter Pi **π** is also correct. See here: [Unicode Table - Greek Small Letter Pi](https://unicode-table.com/en/03C0/)