# Can Julia input Unicode characters in Vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, unicode, julia

From the Julia command line, typing \pi and pressing Tab gives you $\pi$. Is this possible in vsocde or jupyter?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4zw2.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834519/visual-studio-alt-code-symbols

Comment: For vscode, you need Julia [extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/julia). For jupyter, if I remember correctly, [IJulia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl) is enough.

Comment: Are you asking about entering unicode characters in any file using Julia's syntax (significantly more difficult to set up) or just in Julia files (which is what the comment by @Stepan Zakharov clarifies)?

Answer (score 0):

Stepan is correct - VSCode with the Julia extension installed will give you the same Unicode completions as the Julia REPL:

[image]

Then after `<TAB>`:

[image]

Note that you need a running Julia session for this to work.

Comment: Ok thanks, maybe I didn't notice it because I added Tabnine before. Another small question is how to improve the speed of starting julia for the first time? I use vscode to edit, the first compilation takes about 30s, which is too slow.